# Paste SQL Server table diagrams into Word - diagram too small

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ms-word, diagram

Using SQL Server 2008 R2

1. From my workstation, I log into our SQL Server via Remote Desktop and start SQL Server Management Studio.
2. I create a new database diagram and arrange the tables -- the diagram looks fine.
3. I then choose Edit -> Copy Diagram to Clipboard
4. I minimize the Remote desktop session and Paste the diagram into Word (on my workstation).

Unfortunately, the diagram is about 1/5 the size as shown on SQL Server -- I know, I can expand the diagram to make it larger -- but it looks like Cr*p!! and is very unreadable.

Is there something that causes the diagram to be so small when working via Remote Desktop?? (I have no choice as I have to log in to the SQL Server remotely in order to generate the diagram).

Has anyone else had this problem?

All I want to do is copy the diagram from SQL Server to Word (to update some documentation).

Comment: take a screen shot of the data and use that... or use excel?

Comment: First paste it to mspaint. Take a screenshot is good idea.

Comment: @RandomUs1r Always I take screenshot but this time diagram is too big to fit into one screenshot, any tips on how to deal with it?

Comment: @hima can you tell me the approx resolution of your image and Monitor

Answer (score 0):

You can paste into MS paint and then save this as a .bmp file. Then you can send file through file transfer option.

I think this will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

- In database diagram, before copying it, please zoom in to required zoom.
- Copy and paste it into MS paint!

That's it! this will copy zoomed in resolution to the paint and from there exporting to your preferred format is piece of a cake!

Answer (score -1):

use **printscreen button** when diagram is in screen and the paste it into **MS Paint** it will give you exact resolution as of your Monitor.

Comment: This will not work if the db diagram is too huge. Resolution will be really less.